# Do helpful flags help your reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, flags

I have been flagging bad questions and was able to locate in my profile the results of such flagging, but I cannot tell if they affect my reputation at all.

Does anyone know?

Comment: My question was marked as a duplicate.  I searched in the "How does 'Reputation' work" for the keyword "flag" and didn't quite get the answer I was looking for.  I guess I should have asked WHY doesn't flagging affect your reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flagging has nothing to do with reputation. At all.

You get reputation from upvotes, approved suggested edits, accepting and getting answers accepted.

Comment: Why is flagging not included in one's reputation?  If a flag is rated as "helpful" doesn't it positively contribute to SO?

Comment: Oh yeah, we could totally have like a *separate* reputation score for your flags that would show how many of them were marked helpful. What a great idea, why hasn't anyone thought of it?

Answer (score 1):

No, neither helpful nor unhelpful flags have an impact upon your reputation.